# How to get javascript function to delete added todos?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a premade list of `li` in the html which javascript can delete, but once I add another `li` it doesn't delete the new one. I think the problem is the `for` loop, but I don't know another way to solve this. Do you have another way of solving this? I've tried the `e.target.matches` and even `e.target.tagName === 'SPAN'`

```js
/* eslint-disable require-jsdoc */
/* eslint-disable no-invalid-this */
/* eslint-disable no-var */

// select all the needed elements from Java
var deleteTodo = document.querySelectorAll('span');
var strikeThrough = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');

// delete done todos
for (var i = 0; i < deleteTodo.length; i++) {
  deleteTodo[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
      console.log('span clicked');
    }
  });
}

// strikethrough effect on done todos
for (var i = 0; i < strikeThrough.length; i++) {
  strikeThrough[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('li')) {
      this.classList.toggle('done');
    }
  });
}

// add a todo task
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    var newTodo = input.value;
    var newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = '<span>X</span> ' + newTodo;
    this.value = '';
    ul.appendChild(newLi);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>2Do</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <h1>2-Do List</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo" />
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><span>X</span> one</li>
        <li><span>X</span> Two</li>
        <li><span>X</span> Task Three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: AddEventListeners can only work with elements that already exist. When you add a new element, it never existed when the initial listeners were added. You'll need to add a new listener to each new element as it's created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having isn't with the loop itself it's an issue at when you are adding the listeners to the span elements. Since you are adding a new span element you have to add a listener to the new object try something like this.

```
var deleteTodo = document.querySelectorAll('span');
var strikeThrough = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');


const addSpanListeners = function(spanArr){
  for (var i = 0; i < spanArr.length; i++) {
    spanArr[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
        console.log('span clicked');
      }
    });
  }
}


// delete done todos
addSpanListeners(deleteTodo);

// strikethrough effect on done todos
for (var i = 0; i < strikeThrough.length; i++) {
  strikeThrough[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('li')) {
      this.classList.toggle('done');
    }
  });
}

// add a todo task
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    var newTodo = input.value;
    var newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = '<span>X</span> ' + newTodo;
    this.value = '';
    ul.appendChild(newLi);
    deleteTodo = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    addSpanListeners(deleteTodo);
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a new event listener for each new object, or make sure you're using event delegation for a higher level element.

```
// add a todo task
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    var newTodo = input.value;
    var newLi = document.createElement('li');

    var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
        newSpan.innerHTML = "x";
    newLi.innerHTML = ' ' + newTodo;
    newLi.prepend(newSpan);

    this.value = '';


    newSpan.addEventListener("click",function(e){
      /* Click code for new X */
    }

    ul.appendChild(newLi);
  }
});
```